# How can I selectively filter email messages and redirect them from Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

How does one selectively filter an email message and redirect it from Outlook.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the Gear icon to open the options menu.
2. Click "Rules for sorting new messages" under "Customizing Outlook"
3. Click "New" to create a new rule
4. You can act on messages based on

   - Sender's address
   - Sender's name
   - To or Cc line
   - Subject
   - Message has attachments

   Depending on which option you choose you'll additionally compare this a string with "is", "is not", "contains", "does not contain", "begins with", "ends with".
5. Choose the "Forward to" action and put in the email address to which you want to forward
6. Save your rule